# code looped with setInterval delays

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, gallery

I'm trying to make an image fader that cycles through a number of images (3 here).  I made this function to loop and fade in the proper image and it works, fading out one image while fading in the next so that there is no empty space. Except for when it reaches the end of the array the function, it fades the last image in the array out before looping back and fading the first in again, creating an second of empty space.

Javscript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var img_arr = [
            '#img1',
            '#img2',
            '#img3'
        ]
        var i = 0;
        arr_length = img_arr.length;
        //fade function
        function fade_gal() {
            $(img_arr[i])
                .animate(
                    {opacity: '1.0' }, 500
                );
            $('.img').delay(3000).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500);
            i = i + 1;
            if (i == arr_length) {
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        $(document).ready(function img_gallery() {
            //initial function
            fade_gal();
            //set function interval
            setInterval( function() {fade_gal()}, 3500);
        })
    </script>
```

html

```
<div id="scroller">
            <img src="../../images/1.jpg" alt="img1" width="300px" id="img1" class="img"/>
            <img src="../../images/2.jpg" alt="img1" width="300px" id="img2" class="img"/>
            <img src="../../images/3.jpg" alt="img1" width="300px" id="img3" class="img"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: I usually try not to provide whole code in an answer, but here's an alteration that does not have the gap http://jsfiddle.net/FSLZP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
$('.img').delay(3000).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500);
```

to this:

```
$(img_arr[i]).delay(3000).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500);
```

I have a feeling it's that there is a conflict between the fading out and fading in.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a reason to fade all images at every run...

If your images are absolutely positioned with no z-index there is a top one and a bottom one.

All you have to do is fade the top image out, and when it's done, send it to the bottom of the pile.

You can code it like this (EDITED) (here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txLet/) :

```
//fade function
function fade_gal() {
    var container = $('#container');
    var imgs = $('img',container);
    var img = imgs.last();
    img.animate({opacity: '0'}, {duration: 500, complete: function(){
        container.prepend(img); //send image to bottom
        img.css({opacity: 1});
    }});
}
$(document).ready(function img_gallery() {
    //initial function
    fade_gal();
    //set function interval
    setInterval(fade_gal,2000);
})​
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code was confusing to me, not that it was wrong. I couldn't figure out the timings.

This is my version: ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNZ6x/))

```
var img_arr = [
    '#img1',
    '#img2',
    '#img3'
    ];



arr_length = img_arr.length;
var i = arr_length;
//fade function

$('.img').css('opacity', 0.0);

function fade_gal() {

    $(img_arr[(i-1)%arr_length]).animate({opacity: 0.0}, 500);
    $(img_arr[i%arr_length]).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 500);

    i++;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //initial function
    fade_gal()

    //set function interval
    setInterval(function() {
        fade_gal()
    }, 3500);
})​
```